# Switch randomly a predetermined number of elements of a tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am struggling to find a solution to this puzzle. I have:

- **mask**: a 2d tensor of shape=(batch_size, n) which is made by ones and zeros
- **n_neg**: a 1d tensor of shape=(batch_size,) of type int

what I'd like to do is to change, randomly, from 0 to 1 as many elements in each row of mask as indicated in the correspondent row of n_neg. By previous construction this will always be possible, i.e. the number of zeros in the i-th row of **mask** is always greater than **n_neg**[i]. Since it's in the cost function of my model I'd like to do it only exploiting tensorflow ops.

Any idea on how to do it? thanks in advance

Comment: Out of curiosity, can I ask what application you wanted to use this for?

Comment: object detection, to have a "balanced ratio" of positive and negative examples

Comment: I see. Did you find a solution? I took a shot at it when I asked you, but didn't find anything. It's a nice algorithmic challenge too (how to do it optimally).

Comment: It's been a while... if I remember correctly at the end I just used the minimum of **n_neg** for all the batch elements of **mask**